# Is there a checklist for lightning strike?

Tags: lightning, checklist

Is there a specific checklist or procedure to follow, after a confirmed or suspected lightning strike on the aircraft?

Or is a basic scan around the cockpit (plane is flying, no warning lights, no circuit breakers popped) sufficient?

Comment: From a flight crew or maintenance perspective?

Comment: For maintenance: [Boeing Aero magazine](http://www.boeing.com/commercial/aeromagazine/articles/2012_q4/4/) ⌁ and ⌁ [Lufthansa Technik](http://www.lufthansa-technik.com/en/lightning-strikes).

Comment: Which aircraft type/category are you asking about?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the aircrew, at least in the aircraft that I've flown, there is no defined checklist.  You scan and then deal with anything that occurs (inoperative equipment, pressurization issues, whatever you get) with whatever checklists apply: if the lightning knocked out a hydraulic pump, run the checklist for the inop pump, etc.

Once you're on the ground, maintenance has a HUGE checklist to work through, essentially checking every surface of the aircraft for damage and verifying that every piece of equipment still works.  The more that the crew can tell them (i.e. radios & instruments unaffected, no equipment stopped working, pressurization normal, etc), the more of it they can sign off from the crew observation.  But even then, it's still pretty lengthy.

Comment: Agree. The "checklist" is something like: (1) What was that? (2) Was...was that lightning? (3) Does everything still seem to work? (4) Did anything catch on fire or fall off [look outside]? (5) If F/O appears nervous, look at F/O confidently and say "it happens." If no F/O, jump to step 6 immediately. (6) Sip coffee.